# Dynamic portfolio optimization with cumulative prospect theory

Tags: portfolio-optimization, dynamic, behavioral-finance

i'm new to this forum and i hope i can get some help or at least some guidance how to tackle the following problem: I'm tasked to write a VBA Macro that conducts an intertemporal portfolio optimization with prospect theory preferences. As far as i already understand, CPT (cumulative prospect theory) isn't time-separable due to the reference dependence (static ref. point, not dynamic adjusting) and moreover, not time-consistent due to the decision weights. This means i have to write some sort of forward algorithm to recalculate the new path of portfolio allocations for each timestep until the end of my investment horizon. It also means the economic agent revises her/his strategy at any point in time and thus the usual Bellman approach cannot be used. I tried to understand the problem using an intertemp. Lagrange optimization just to get a feeling for the Euler Equations and i guess 'm running into some computational issues...but thats not my question, however, any hints are appreciated here.

well..What i have tried is this: So far i simulated for a binomial tree each possible strategy, calculated conditional probabilities for those strategies, that are feasible, calculated the CPT utility and picked the path/allocation with the highest CPT. I know this is some stupid brute force approach and there are surely more clever ways to handle this. Moreover, this problem gets really complex once i exceed five timesteps (and my Excel refuses to go on as i reach my storage limit after seven steps).

My question is, whether sthere is some sort of example-VBA code or excel sheet that demonstrates this dynamic programming / intertemporal portfolio optimization problem where the solutions cannot be simply obtained by Bellman. Any hints whether i'm on the right track is highly appreciated.
All best

Comment: Hi, welcome! It seems your approach is based on Nicholas Barberis (2010) A Model of Casino Gambling? I remember he did something similar with a slightly different focus https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1398343